# How to show the distance in kilometer on activity using google map in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-maps

I am trying to get the distance of the nearby event from my location (from google map) and show it on the activity. But I am not sure which button I need to use to show the distance and what is the java code to show the distance in kilometer on the activity?

Answer (score 0):

If you know your current LatLong or your targeted location lat long then you can find Distance using following method.

```
public double findDistance(LatLng fromLatLan, LatLng toLatLan) {
        int earthRadious = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
        double latFrom = fromLatLan.latitude;
        double latTo = toLatLan.latitude;
        double lonFrom = fromLatLan.longitude;
        double lonTo = toLatLan.longitude;

        double diffLat = Math.toRadians(latTo - latFrom);
        double diffLon = Math.toRadians(lonTo - lonFrom);

        double aValue = Math.sin(diffLat / 2) * Math.sin(diffLat / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latFrom))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latTo)) * Math.sin(diffLon / 2)
                * Math.sin(diffLon / 2);

        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(aValue));
        double results = earthRadious * c;

        double kms = results / 1;
        DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
        int killoMeter = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(kms));

        double meter = results % 1000;
        int metersDistance = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));


        Log.i("Value", "" + results + "   KilloMeter  " + killoMeter
                + " Meter   " + metersDistance);

        return earthRadious * c;
    }
```

Comment: thank you but how to show the distance in KM on activity??and which button should i use ? how to link the button to get the distance directly from google map? I m new in android so please help me.